# How to manage global state in iOS/Android?

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native

I used to use `react-native` to develop mobile apps, for many reasons I have given up on it. But 1 thing I do like about JavaScrip apps is that you have state containers such as `redux`.

**I wonder how people manage global states in iOS and Android?**

Two scenarios to help you understand my question:

1. A user has logged in. When the user is navigating between screens, how do I know if the user is logged in? Do I have to pass the `currentUser` property around?
2. Suppose I am writing a twitter clone, a user can `like` a tweet or click on it and then go to another page to see the detail of the tweet. The user can also `like` the tweet on the detail screen. Upon returning, the `like` button on the main screen is also activated because the user `liked` this tweet on the detail screen.

Both things can be done in `react` or `react-native` using

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps)
```

I wonder what are the iOS and Android approach for achieving this?

Comment: Short answer: Sqlite is available on both. Android though - http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering to point [In context to android]
1. In order to maintain user login states through multiple screens/activities, you can maintain user login state in android shared preferences and may be make a class MiscUtils with a function

```
public static isUserLoggedIn()
{
return userLoginState//Based on the variable you stored in shared preference
}
```

And now you can use this function, and add more functions in this class to access user properties in several activities.

2. If the user has liked a tweet in activity A and goes to details activity say B, since B gets all its data from A (which has the tweet liked variable), B will show the tweet like, or you could fetch the details from the network. In either case the tweet will be liked, now of the scenario is like this, that user likes the tweet in B and comes back to A, there is something called startActivityForResult in Android, using which you can set result inn Activity B [stating the properties changed, in a bundle and ofcourse updating the data, wherever you have stored it] and inn Activity A in onActivityResult you could use those properties [set by activity B], to show the updated ui

Answer (score 0):

You can use [reductor](https://github.com/Yarikx/reductor) which is the redux variant for Java/Android.

Reductor can help you make your state mutations easier to read, write and reason about. It leverages annotation processing to validate correctness and generate boilerplate code at compile time, allowing you to express state reducers in a concise way as pure java functions. It also complies with Redux principles:

1. Single source of truth
2. State is read-only
3. Changes are made with pure
           functions